# How to configure webpack-serve?

Tags: webpack, webpack-serve

I was trying to set up a webpack development server, following the tutorial, in which it is done with `webpack-dev-server`, but since it doesn't work with `webpack-cli v4`, I decided to use `webpack-serve` (version 3.2.0). My folder structure looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DIchy.jpg).
index.js and test.js are bundled, they are supposed to log some number and a string to the console, index.html in dist folder is connected to bundle.js. My package.json is:

```
{
  "name": "forkify",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "forkify project",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack --mode development",
    "build": "webpack --mode production",
    "start": "webpack-serve --config webpack.config.js --host localhost --port 8080 --open"
  },
  "author": "Alex",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack": "^5.1.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.0.0",
    "webpack-serve": "^3.2.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {}
}
```

and webpack.config.js looks like this:

```
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  entry: "./src/js/index.js",
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist/js"),
    filename: "bundle.js",
  },
  devServer: {
    contentBase: "./dist",
  },
};
```

When I run `"start"` script, it opens a page with 'Not found / 404' error, [here](https://github.com/shellscape/webpack-plugin-serve/blob/master/.github/FAQ.md#what-does-the-not-found--404-error-mean) it says, that it must be trying to serve index file, but couldn't find one. When in `"start"` script I do not specify host  and port, it opens a page on http://[::]:55555/ and I get 'Unable to connect error', nothing from my bundle gets logged to the console. Path seems fine to me. Changing `devServer` to `serve` in webpack.config.js produces an error in the command line: configuration has an unknown property 'serve'. Please help me find the problem and get the  server running.

Answer (score 2):

Try with below configuration,

```json
{
 "webpack": "^5.1.3",
 "webpack-cli": "^3.3.12",
 "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.0"
}
```

```json
"scripts": {
  "start": "webpack-dev-server --config webpack.config.js --host localhost --port 8080 --open"
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've circumvented the problem by setting the following versions of devDependencies: webpack": "^4.2.0", "webpack-cli": "^2.0.12", "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.1" (like in tutorial, that I followed). But I would like to run the script using webpack-serve, and the latest versions of other devDependencies.